# NPM.JS plugin for accessing the linux terminal

Tags: linux, node.js, bash, npm

Here is my situation. I'm working on an application that uses node.js. However, I cannot find a plugin that will shut down the system without any intervention. I figured that if I can access bash (the command line for linux) I should be able to enter `shutdown -h -P now`. Ideally, the code would look something like this:

```
var commander = require('commander'); // Example

commander.command("shutdown -h -P now");
```

and it would shut down the system. Thanks for reading this, and for your help! If you can find either a module that will shutdown the system, or a module that can access the terminal, that would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

I think this is built in native.  https://nodejs.org/api/child_process.html.

You can google around for examples.

Also. You can check out the shell.js module